# How to click a button in Qt WebEngine?

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

How to click a button in the newest Qt5.7 `WebEngine`?
In the past `Webkit`, we could do this to click a button:

```
QWebElement button = frame->findFirstElement("input[id=search]");
button.evaluateJavaScript("this.click()");
```

So, how can I do the same thing with Qt `WebEngine`?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move code that finds button to JavaScript, for example

```
var button = document.querySelector("input[id=search]");
if (button) {
  button.click();
}
```

Then execute your JavaScript code with `QWebEnginePage::runJavaScript()`.

Comment: Works perfectly.